# Efficient way of parsing string

Tags: python, string, parsing

How would you turn a string that looks like this

`7.11,8,9:00,9:15,14:30,15:00`

into this dictionary entry

`{7.11 : [8, (9:00, 9:15), (14:30, 15:00)]}`?

Suppose that the number of time pairs (such as `9:00,9:15` and `14:30,15:00` is unknown and you want to have them all as tuple pairs.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Stuart I've used split(',') and then created added the entries to a dictionary from there, but I'm stuck on what I'm supposed to do if the number of time pairs is unknown.

Comment: Is this the only format it will be in?

Comment: @Axium aside from the number of time pairs being variable, yes

Comment: @Ali So it could be like `7.11,8,9:00,9:15,14:30,15:00,15:30,16:00`? Or are the values just variable to change?

Comment: Is the dictionary supposed to contain only strings, or do you need to turn the numbers and times into some other types of objects (i.e. `float`, `int` and maybe `datetime.time`)?

Comment: @Axium the first thing you said

Answer (score 1):

First split the string at the commas, then [zip cluster](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) starting from the 3rd element and put it into a dictionary:

```
s = "7.11,8,9:00,9:15,14:30,15:00"
ss = s.split(',')
d = {ss[0]: [ss[1]] + list(zip(*[iter(ss[2:])]*2))}
```

Output:

```
{'7.11': ['8', ('9:00', '9:15'), ('14:30', '15:00')]}
```

If you need to convert it from string to appropiate data types (you'll have to adapt it according to your needs), then after getting the ss list:

```
time_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(t,'%H:%M').time() for t in ss[2:]]
d = {float(ss[0]): [int(ss[1])] + list(zip(*[iter(time_list)]*2))}
```

Comment: You could also do `key, first_val, *rest = s.split(',')` rather than indexing and slicing, if you want. And consider using `[first_val, *zip(...)]` to build the inner list. I think some of those `*` shenanigans are Python 3.5+ only, but that's getting safer to assume these days (as 3.4 has reached EOL as of this past March).

Comment: @Blckknght `key, first_val, *rest = s.split(',')` is much more elegant, thanks. Building the list with `[first_val, *zip(...)]` I get an error: *can use starred expression only as assignment target*. (Python 3.4.3)

Comment: Yep, that syntax was added in 3.5 (see [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)). You should consider upgrading your Python, 3.4.3 is almost four and a half years old, and is no longer supported by the Python developers (and it probably has some security issues that were fixed in later 3.4 releases).

Comment: @Blckknght Yeah,I should indeed I guess. Thanks again for the improvements.